# Converting a string that looks like a list of dicts into an actual list

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a columns in a dataframe that look like list of dictionaries, but they are of type string. However, they are not in JSON format (properties are not enclosed in double quotes)

**`df` display:**

| col |
| --- |
| [{name=john, userid=john-doe, age=23}, {name=mary, userid=mary-smith, age=21}] |

What I want to do is iterate over the dictionaries in the list in a for loop. However I am having trouble converting the string into an actual Python list.

```
print(df['col'].dtype)
>>> object
```

```
for info in df['col']:
   print(info)
   print(type(info))
>>> [{name=john, userid=john-doe, age=23}, {name=mary, userid=mary-smith, age=21}]
>>> <class 'str'>
```

If I use `json.loads`, I get an error:

```
for info in df['col']:
   for i in json.loads(info):
   ...do work
>>> JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

I also tried `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
for info in df['col']:
   for i in ast.literal_eval(info):
   ...do work
>>> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Simply casting it to a list only makes it return the '[' part of the string:

```
for info in df['col']:
   for i in list(info):
     print(i)
>>> [
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom function:

```
f = lambda x: [dict([z.split('=') for z in y.split(', ')]) for y in x.strip('[{}] ').split('}, {')]
df['new'] = df['col'].apply(f)
```

List comprehenesion alternative:

```
df['new'] = [[dict([z.split('=') for z in y.split(', ')]) for y in x.strip('[{}] ').split('}, {')] for x in df['col']]
```